# The more complex notation of the Structure Dereference operator in C, ->?

Tags: c, operators, structure, dereference

I have an exam question question here which asks:

"The C operator -> is a shorthand for a more complex notation. Explain the circumstances in which -> or the more complex notation would be used. Write an example of the more complex notation."

I`m not sure what the examiner is looking for here. My impression is that there is only one way to denote a structure dereference and that is ->. Can anyone help?

Comment: How would you dereference an object (not to access a member; just dereference it)? If you have an object (not a pointer), how do you access a member?

Comment: Do some research before asking here, you clearly know that it is shorthand for dereference ... so how could we figure out the other notation... [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=c%20dereference&=&oq=&gs_l=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dereferencing can be done either by using `->` or `(*).`. See the example

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
struct point my_point = { 3, 7 };
struct point *p = &my_point;  /* To declare and define p as a pointer of type struct point,
                                 and initialize it with the address of my_point. */

(*p).x = 8;                   /* To access the first member of the struct */
p->x = 8;
```

Most probably your teacher was asking for `(*p).x = 8;`.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` syntax is a shorthand for `(*).` syntax, so `struct->member` is equivalent to `(*struct).member`.

Parenthesis are mandatory because of [operator priority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), basically here the member-access (`.`) operator has a greater priority than the dereferencing (`*`) operator.

Remember, programmers are lazy and often like shortcuts.